# Is it possible to have Code Analysis warnings formatted like normal ones?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, unmanaged

I like the code analysis included in VS2012. But it's a bit annoying that the warnings are only processable in the Code Analysis window, and not by stepping through the build output with <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation? How could I format the output of the static code analysis like normal compiler output (i.e. don't only print the filename but the correct path to the file being inspected)?

I'm not using FxCop since I'm working with unmanaged code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unmanaged code analysis, the MSBuild scripts use `/analyze:quiet` instead of `/analyze` in order to prevent writing results to the error list.  The simplest way to change the behavior would be to modify your `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets` file (typically located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Targets`) to avoid specifying quiet mode.  i.e.: Change the line

```
<AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(PlatformToolsetVersion)'&gt;='110'">%(ClCompile.AdditionalOptions)  /analyze:quiet</AdditionalOptions>
```

to

```
<AdditionalOptions Condition="'$(PlatformToolsetVersion)'&gt;='110'">%(ClCompile.AdditionalOptions)  /analyze</AdditionalOptions>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm not talking about FxCop but the analysis for unmanaged files. Updated question.

Comment: They're essentially the same thing under the hood.  VS Code Analysis is a VS integration wrapper for the FxCop engine.  It uses an MSBuild task to run the `fxcopcmd.exe` executable to run analyses, and the `CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions` inserts command line options to the call.  If you increase the verbosity on your VS build output, you'll be able to see the full command line generated by the task in your VS output window.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the "unmanaged" part.  I still think of it as "PREfast".  I'll update my answer to cover the scenario.

Comment: Hmmm... I swear this used to work in VS2013 as well... seems it is not working now. :-/

Comment: It seems this still writes the warnings to the Output window, but they are just simply not picked up by the error/warning list. -- Not sure what gives here.