# Display MSBuild warning in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

I work in a continuous integration environment.
Jenkins build my C# solution and display a lot of warning.

Here is an example of warning display :
[image: jenkins]

In order to fix them, I want to get them in Visual Studio (and use vs' tools to debug them). Unfortunately, my warning list is empty :

[image: vs2012]

How is it possible to configure VS 2012 in order to display MSBuild warning in Visual Studio ?
I already tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111524/is-it-possible-to-have-code-analysis-warnings-formatted-like-normal-ones) or [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzzzth4(v=vs.90).aspx), but doesn't work.

On the other side, when I browse the Code Analysis complete rules list, I cannot find the previous category :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CI Platform should be compiling in `Release` mode. Are you compiling in `Release` or in `Debug` within VS?

Code Analysis rule set are usually different between these two modes.

Comment: Running them after compiling in `Release` show me a lot of warning. Thanks !